# Problemas con el sistema operativo ubuntu

Tags: keyboard

Community, I have a question, in my operating system I have detected that the keyboard stops responding even with an external keyboard, in the same way the mouse when clicking does not work, the behavior of the operating system is unexpected when pressing keys and new windows open .

Could it be something physical about the laptop or the operating system?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us more details. Put the title in English, and then tell us what hardware you are using, what flavor of Ubuntu, explain what "unexpected" means, (what windows? What keys?). When does the keyboard stop responding? Is there a trigger? Is it random? Does it happen sometimes? Always? Does it work for a while and then stop working?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].